# zsh not always expanding path

Tags: shell, zsh

If I type `rpm --root=/` in ZSH and then press TAB nothing happens. This works for a lot of other commands. How can I make ZSH always expand the path like in BASH?

Comment: As a workaround for this particular case, just drop the `=` and do `rpm --root /<tab>`

Comment: zsh's completion isn't as smart as bash w.r.t. `=`. It is my understanding that it needs to be defined by the completion definitions for _each_ command separately.  @WilliamPursell's workaround is how I do it. Some commands require the equals sign, so I put it back after completion.  If the file is one you've used in a past argument, you can complete it by hitting `Esc` and then `.` (or on some terminals, `Alt+/`).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're still using Zsh's legacy completion system. To upgrade to the "new" completion system (released in the year 2000), add this to your `.zshrc` file:

```sh
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

Then you'll see that pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `rpm --root=/` will give you file completions just fine.