# Zsh does not expand path in `--flag=path` style arguments

Tags: zsh, expansion, pathname, variable-expansion

In bash:

```
$ foo --bar=/tmp/ba<tab>
```

expands to `foo --bar/tmp/baz`. In my zsh install, no expansion is performed here (but is performed as expected when the path is separated by whitespace, i.e. `foo --bar /tmp/ba<tab>`). What zsh setting do I need to enable to make this work?

I'm running zsh 5.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0). The problem occurs with out-of-the-box zsh (no .zshrc).

Note that this question duplicates [zsh not always expanding path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102699/zsh-not-always-expanding-path), but I'm posting it here since that question lacks a descriptive title and details (and has no answers after four years).

Answer (score 1):

```
setopt MAGIC_EQUAL_SUBST
```

should do the trick in most cases.

It may not work, if there are specific settings in the completion system for the command and parameter in question. But then again, these settings should be that way for a reason.